# perl cgi print header charset not work

Tags: perl, character-encoding, cgi

I have a perl cgi program which output to a simple html form for user data input.
The form is in chinese big5 charset

When opened the cgi script, I have to manual switch web browser charset encoding to big5.

I searched on google and I found a method to set charset. Then

original code

```
$q = new CGI;
print $q->header;
```

to new code

```
$q = new CGI;
print $q->header(-charset=>'big5');
```

However, it just output a blank html.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header(-charset => 'big5');
print '簡體字';
```

When i try it, it will be showed correctly. (Make sure, that your script is also saved in big5).

Answer (score 1):

If those are the only two lines, then it's probably working.

Run the cgi from command line and you should see:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=big5
```

Comment: i tried Paulchenkiller's code. The same problem, returned a blank page. I'm sure the file is saved in big5 unix format.

Running from command line, I could see 

      Content-Type: text/html; charset=big5

Comment: This is my apache virtual setup


<VirtualHost 192.168.1.3>
       ServerAdmin support@abc.com
       DocumentRoot /www/abc/public_html
        <Directory /www/abc/public_html>
                Options +ExecCGI +Includes
                AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
        </Directory>
       ServerName www.abc.com
       ServerAlias abc.com
       ScriptAlias /public_html/ /www/abc/public_html/
       ErrorLog logs/abc_error_log
       CustomLog logs/abc_access_log common
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0):

You're printing headers, but no content, so the page will be blank. Use Firebug or similar to verify the response from the server.